# this.props.SignupUser is not a function in my SignupComponent file What is the problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux

**Here is the SignupComponent.js where i am getting error this.props.SignupUser is not a function. What should i do now can someone help please**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Col, FormFeedback } from 'reactstrap';


class Signup extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.handleSignup = this.handleSignup.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isNavOpen: false,
      isModalOpen: false
    };
}

/*constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state ={
    firstname:'',
    lastname:'',
    username:'',
    email:'',
    password:''
   }
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSignup = this.handleSignup.bind(this);
}
handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}*/

//signup
handleSignup(values) {
    this.props.SignupUser(values.firstname,values.lastname,values.email,values.username,values.password);
}
render() {
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-5">
                    <h3>Sign up</h3>
                    <hr />
                </div> 
            </div>

            <Form onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSignup(values)}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="firstname">firstname</Label>
                            <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange}
                            innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                                 />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="lastname">lastname</Label>
                            <Input type="lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange}
                            innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                                 />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="username">username</Label>
                            <Input type="username" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.handleChange}
                            innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                                 />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="email">email</Label>
                            <Input type="email" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange}
                            innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                                 />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="password">password</Label>
                            <Input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange}
                            innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                                  />
                        </FormGroup>
                        <Button type="submit" value="submit" color="primary">Sign up</Button>
                        <a href="/login"> Have Acccount</a>
                    </Form>
                </div>
    );


}
}

 export default Signup;
```

**here is the ActionCreater.js**

```
//signup process
export const requestSignup = (creds) => {
return {
    type: ActionTypes.SIGNUP_REQUEST,
    creds
}
}

export const receiveSignup = (response) => {
return {
    type: ActionTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    token: response.token
}
}

 export const SignupError = (message) => {
return {
    type: ActionTypes.SIGNUP_FAILURE,
    message
}
}

export const SignupUser = (firstname,lastname,email,password,username) => (dispatch) => {

const newUser = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    password:password,
    username:username
}
console.log('User ', newUser);


return fetch(baseUrl + 'users/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(newUser),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response;
    }
    else {
        var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
},
error => {
    var errmess = new Error(error.message);
    throw errmess;
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => dispatch(receiveSignup(response)))
.catch(error => { console.log('Post comments ', error.message);
    alert('Your comment could not be posted\nError: '+ error.message); })
}
```

**What i am trying to do is i want to save the user into the mongodb through the signup process the backend is working perfectly but when i am trying to connect to client then there is an error**

Comment: Where do you set "dispatch" to this method? as i can see, you used dispatch inside the SignupUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your  `SignupComponent.js` I can see that you havn't used `mapDispatchToProps`to dispatch the actions. When you write it, will get `SignupUser` action into components props.

First import `SignupUser` action from `ActionCreater.js` into your `SignupComponent.js` and then try by adding this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps() {
    return {
        SignupUser: SignupUser
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Signup);
```

Comment: Thank's for you help the code is working now but when i am filling the form the values is undefined. The values which i am inserting into the form are replaced with undefirnd value or empty string. What should i do now please help

Answer (score 0):

You have not called redux to dispatch the SignupUser function inside the Signup component yet

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { SignupUser } from './ActionCreater.js';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Col, FormFeedback } from 'reactstrap';

class Signup extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.handleSignup = this.handleSignup.bind(this);

  this.state = {
    isNavOpen: false,
    isModalOpen: false
  };
}

/*constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state ={
      firstname:'',
      lastname:'',
       username:'',
       email:'',
       password:''
   }
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.handleSignup = this.handleSignup.bind(this);
 }
 handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
       [e.target.id]: e.target.value
 })
}*/

 //signup
 handleSignup(values){ this.props.dispatchSignUpUser(values.firstname,values.lastname,values.email,values.username,values.password);
   }
   render() {
   return(
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-5">
                <h3>Sign up</h3>
                <hr />
            </div> 
        </div>

        <Form onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSignup(values)}>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label htmlFor="firstname">firstname</Label>
                        <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                             />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label htmlFor="lastname">lastname</Label>
                        <Input type="lastname" id="lastname" name="lastname" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                             />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label htmlFor="username">username</Label>
                        <Input type="username" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                             />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label htmlFor="email">email</Label>
                        <Input type="email" id="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                             />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Label htmlFor="password">password</Label>
                        <Input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        innerRef={(input) => this.username = input}
                              />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <Button type="submit" value="submit" color="primary">Sign up</Button>
                    <a href="/login"> Have Acccount</a>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const actionCreators = {
     dispatchSignUpUser: SignupUser,
}

export default connect(null, actionCreators) (Signup);
```